# listbox not showing any results

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want my listbox in visual studio to list the courses in my course table (from the database)
the application runs fine but the listBox remains empty this is the code I'm using:

```
  protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlcon = "Data Source = localhost; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = localhost; Password = ****; Unicode = True";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(sqlcon);
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "select coursename from course";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        while(dr.Read())
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have just one record in your table?

Comment: And are you trying to add items to the same listbox that triggered the SelectedIndexChanged event?

Answer (score 0):

There are at leat three errors in your code and some logic problem.

**Errors first:**

- You call read without doing anything with the record loaded by the
  read.
- When you reach the loop code you have already loaded the first record, so the Read inside the while just try to load the second record. But if there is just one record the loop never runs and thus there are no items in the list
- You call GetString(1) but you retrieve just the coursename from the
  table and this will give an exception for index out of range. Arrays
  start at index zero so to get the coursename you need GetString(0)

  ```
  // Not needed, let the loop run
  // dr.Read();
  while(dr.Read())
  {
      // The first column is at index zero 
      ListBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
  }
  ```

Finally the logic problem. It seems that you use the SelectedIndexChanged event to fill the items of the same list that triggers the SelectedIndexChanged. This seems to be illogic because you have already items in that list and selecting one triggered the event. This code should be run somewhere else (The Load event?) What are you trying to do here? Anyway, if you really want to keep this code then you should at least clearing the Items collection before loading items from the database otherwise, at each SelectedIndexChanged you add another set of item identical to the already loaded one.

```
  // Before filling the items clear the previous ones
  listBox1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: i am open to any suggestions it's not necessary to stick with this code my main goal is to be able to select from the items that will appear in this list to another empty list then insert them as student suggestions in the database

Comment: Then this approach makes sense if you change any reference from listBox1 to (for example) listBox2 where you add the coursenames. In other words, the SelectedIndexChanged event for the listBox1 triggers this event handler and here you fill the second listbox, but probably you need to have a WHERE condition in your query that filters the coursenames with the condition expressed by the item choosen in the first listbox